# execute command on pointer movement, wait and revert?

Tags: x11, mouse, daemon, key-mapping, xmodmap

I've got two pointing devices (touchpad and trackpoint) and the goal is to execute a command when movement (any direction, any distance) is detected on the trackpoint, then wait a configurable amount of time and if by then no other movement has been detected, execute another command.

The final goal is to temporarily remap (f.e. with xmodmap) some keys to mouse clicks and revert back the keys to their normal function once the timer is up(so similar in functionality like disabling the touchpad while typing).

How could I go about that? Target system is Linux, unix agnostic solution would be better. Bonus points for not needing root. Thanks for any help.